# Sql data sorted by calendar date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Data sorted weekly only for the calendar days..Ex Feb 1, 2013 is a Friday, in need to pull in the data for Feb 1 & 2.  RIght now it pulls the data for the entire week of 1-27-2013 to 2-2-2013. My results put in the total billed for the week end dates. EX( 1-5-13, 1-12-13)  For the end of January and the beginning of Feburary I need the results to look like 1-27-13 to 1-31-13 = "total" with the week ending date to be the 31st. For Febuary 2-1-13 to 2-2-13 = "total"

I have been able to do it by individual days, but thats not how "Accounting" wants it.

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(week, DATEdiff(WK, 0, bd.[Service Date 1]) ,5) AS month, 
    bd.Chart, 
    bd.[Transaction Code], 
    SUM(bd.Units) AS [Total Billed]

FROM dbo.[Billing Detail] AS bd 

INNER JOIN dbo.Patient AS p ON bd.Chart = p.[Chart Number]
WHERE

    (bd.[Transaction Code] = 'H2016') 
    AND (bd.[Service Date 1] >= '01/01/2013') 
    AND (bd.[Service Date 1] < '12/31/2013')

GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(week, DATEdiff(WK, 0, bd.[Service Date 1]) ,5), 
    bd.Chart, 
    bd.[Transaction Code]

ORDER BY bd.Chart
```

Comment: Please ident code to easily understand your problem

Answer (score 3):

Just add to your select list (and group by list) two fields:

```
...
MONTH([Service Date 1]),
DATEPART(week,[Service Date 1])
...
```

and that should do it

Comment: I added this to my query, and it does break it down the way that I need it to look. the only thing is, for the date it gives me 01-01-2013 for everything in January and 2-1-2013 for everything in Feburary.  It should give me the date for the end of the week EX 1-26-13, 1-31-13, 2-2-13.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure when you posted your comment...  I edited my answer after I posted it, as I had a date hard-coded into the DATEPART function.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a stored procedure that takes a date variable as an input parameter.  It would start like this:

```
declare @dateIn as date;
declare @EndOfWeek as date;
declare @StartOfWeek as date;
declare @WeekEndsOn as int;

set @WeekEndsOn = 6;  -- Friday
if datepart(dw, @dateIn) <= @WeekEndsOn
set @EndOfWeek = dateadd(day, @WeekEndsOn - datepart(dw, @dateIn), @dateIn);
else
set @EndOfWeek = dateadd(day, (7 + @WeekEndsOn) - datepart(dw, @dateIn), @dateIn)
```

Then you run your query using the @StartOfWeek and @EndOfWeek variables.  You can use a combination of convert() and concatonation to get strings like this, "2-1-13 to 2-2-13 ".

In fact you might want to have @WeekEndsOn as an input parameter as well, just in case it changes.

Comment: Here is my output.  Where is says 2013-02-02
 I need it to say:
 2013-01-31   AAAAAA   H2016 4 
Then the next line should be:
2013-02-02  AAAAAA  H2016  2
Since there was 4 days that week that had data (Monday-Thursday) and
 2 days for the next month (Friday and Saturday)
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 AAAAAAAA H2016 5
2013-01-12 00:00:00.000 AAAAAAAA H2016 7
2013-01-19 00:00:00.000 AAAAAAAA H2016 7
2013-01-26 00:00:00.000 AAAAAAAA H2016 7
2013-02-02 00:00:00.000 AAAAAAAA H2016 7
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 BBBBBBBBB H2016 5

2013-02-02 00:00:00.000 BBBBBBBBB H2016 7

Comment: Sorry for the jumbled up output, it will not post it the way that it shows in the edit feild.

Comment: I changed my answer a bit.  To get formatted output, edit your question by adding the sql you tried and the results you got.

Comment: I ran your answer, then I ran my query that I posted up top.  I ended up with the same results.  The output for the week of 1-27-13 to 2-2-13 should be broken up.  I need the results to show what was billed up to 1-31-13, and on a seperate line the results for 2-2-13, Since there was 5 days in the billing cycle that are in January, and 2 billing days in Febuary in the same week.  right now my output gives me the last day of the week "2-2-2013" with a billing of "7".  Thanks for your time.